# I want to develop a android sdk for our clients to use,how to ensure that only the client who apply for an APP_KEY can use my sdk?

Tags: android, sdk, verification

Developers or clients who want to use my skd should go to my website to apply for a APP_KEY.To apply for a APP_KEY,they should offer the app's **package name**,something like this "com.edward.myapp".Also the **SHA-1 of the developers's certificate(generated from keytool)**.
Now I can only send the APP_KEY to my server to verify the APP_KEY,the only thing I know is that the APP_KEY is valid or invalid.But I don't know if it is my clients' app,it can be anyone else's app,and it can be any package name.I don't want to something like this happen.
So how can I verify it to ensure it is the right app to use the sdk?

Comment: any effort to solve the issue?

Comment: I tried store my cert in android's raw folder,and then get the package name like this: this.mPacName=mContext.getPackageName();     and tried to calculate the SHA-1 of the cert.Finally use the package name and the SHA-1 calculated above to generate a value,use this value to compare with the APP_KEY stored in the Manifest file.But someone can still steal it to his app and use my sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Your SDK at runtime can obtain the SHA1 of the certificate used to sign the APK.

```
String getSignatureSha1(Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo info = null;
    try {
        info = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not find info for " + context.getPackageName());
        return null;
    }

    byte[] signatureBytes = info.signatures[0].toByteArray();
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    md.update(signatureBytes);
    byte[] digestBytes = md.digest();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < digestBytes.length; i++) {
        // you can omit this if block if you don't care about the colon separators
        if (i > 0) { 
            builder.append(':');
        }
        builder.append(String.format("%02X", digestBytes[i] & 0xFF));
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

You should do this once when the app starts and cache the result if you need it more than once.